# AJAX call is not working in IIS 7 and windows 7, the same application is running in Windows XP and IIS 5

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis

AJAX call is not working in IIS 7 and windows 7, the same application is running in XP and IIS 5.

I am calling a web-service using AJAX, when I deploy this application in IIS 5 and and windows XP and browse using IE 7 it works.
When I deploy this application in IIS 7 on windows 7 and try to browse it using IE 7 it doesn't works.
Please help me out.

Here is the sample code where i call AJAX.

```js
function UpdateSLDataByRow(strWebServicePath, strServerKey) {
 alert("Update SL Data by row called");
    $(function() {         
 
         var obj1 = { "strServerKey": strServerKey};
        
       var arg = JSON.stringify(obj1);
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            url: strWebServicePath + "/UpdateSLDataByRow",
            data: arg,
 

 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                if (typeof console != "undefined") {
                    if (data.d == 1) {
                        console.log('Transaction Status: OK');
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('Transaction Status: NG');
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                if (typeof console != "undefined") {
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    alert(sJSSLWebServicePathError);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Dear #Mairaj Ahmad, it shows no error, just doesn't accomplish the task. I mean i am inserting  data from one grid view to another through web service. AJAX doesn't invokes the web service.

Comment: See browser console for errors and make sure path is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Let me check that if i get any error  in s IE 7.

Comment: did you figure out what was wrong? I have the same exact issue